# How to automatically map POJOs to database to create tables using NetBeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, pojo

I have wrote some POJOs in NetBeans, and want to map these entities automatically to an empty database, to be tables.

I have read the netbeans official tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#06a

But using `Hibernate Mapping File` as the document says can not choose the `Database Table` value, compare to the pic
[image]

(https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/70/java/hibernate-j2se/mapping-wizard.png,

The `actor` value will not show since my database is empty.

So what should I do if I followed the tutorial, or is there any other method to automatically create tables by POJO in NetBeans?

Answer (score 1):

There is one property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in hibernate which create tables as per your pojo structure.

Refer [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) doc.

Comment: I found SchemaExport more useful, since `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in xml configuration configures Hibernate to do it each time the session factory is created

Answer (score 0):

Use `SchemaExport.export`. Run following code in `main()` method:

```
 AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
 SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration);
 schemaExport.export(true, true, true, false);
```